# Laravel eloquent change attribute by field name

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

My model structure after  model -> find($id);

```
  protected 'attributes' => 
    array (size=35)
      'id' => string '1234134' (length=6)
      'case' => string '123123' (length=7)
```

I want to update this model like this

```
foreach($input as $key => $value){
                var_dump($key);
                $case->($key)= $value;
            }
    $case -> save();
```

I tried like this  but doesn't work

```
$reflection = new \ReflectionClass($case);  
    foreach($input as $key => $value){
                var_dump($key);
                $reflection->"$ke"y;
            }
```

Comment: You should use curly brackets instead of round brackets. Example: $case->{$key}

Comment: I didnt know I could access just like array for eloquent object. I can just do like Case[$key] = $value

Comment: No, you can't. What you are showing are square brackets. I'm talking about using curly brackets. Curly brackets are used to denote string or variable interpolation in PHP.

Comment: Yes but i just used  Case[$key] = $value; like this and worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if this is a laravel eloquent model, you could utilize the use of the `fill` method.

```
$case->fill($input);
$case->save();
```

Comment: but it only works when I have attribute name in fillable

Answer (score 2):

The following code should work.

```
$reflection = new \ReflectionClass($case);

foreach($input as $key => $value){
    var_dump($key);
    $reflection->{$key} = $value;
}

$case->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your syntax is a bit off, try this:

```
foreach($input as $key => $value){
    $case->{$key} = $value;
}

$case->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are trying to access a property of the object in a way that PHP is not supporting.

To access a property of the object by using a variable containing it's name you need to use string interpolation. [Wikipedia - String Interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation)
you can achieve this by using **curly brackets {}** instead of **round brackets ()**

You can fix your example like this:

```
foreach($input as $key => $value){
    $case->{$key}= $value;
}
$case->save();
```

By the way in PHP this can be achieved almost like in your second example but without the double quotes

```
 foreach($input as $key => $value){
    $case->$key= $value;
 }
 $case->save();
```

I personally prefer using curly brackets as it's showing more clearly that I'm using the string value of the variable.